# Working on Linux-How to add a system call from the basics?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am new to Linux. I want to add a system call to linux. But I don't know from where to begin.Can somebody please guide me through the whole process? From installing Linux to getting the kernel source code. I don't know where will I run or test or write the modified source code. Please help me with that also. I searched online for the linux kernel source code but it is giving me a lot of options of GIT files. What are they? How do I install them?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good tutorials for adding system calls to kernel

http://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/
http://blog.techveda.org/adding-system-calls-linux-kernel-3-5-x/
http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~sandhya/csc256/assignments/adding-a-system-call.html
http://seshagiriprabhu.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/adding-a-simple-system-call-to-the-linux-3-2-0-kernel-from-scratch/
http://appusajeev.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/implementing-a-system-call-in-linux-kernel-2-6-35/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html)  . It gives you brief information on system calls and basic tutorials demonstrating their role in Linux Kernel.